# program.exe (C) has stopped working

Tags: c

I am extremely new to C and managed to compile this program, but the exe stops working upon running. I'm really not sure what's wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define TINY 1.0e-20    // A small number.

void ludcmp(float a[3][3], int n, int *indx, float *d);
void lubksb(float a[3][3], int n, int *indx, float b[]) ;

int main(){
    int i,n,*indx;
    float *b,d;
    float a[3][3] = {
        { 1.0, 2.0, 5.0},
        {-1.0, 2.0, 3.0},
        { 6.0, 0.0, 1.0}
    };

    ludcmp(a,n,indx,&d);
    lubksb(a,n,indx,b);

    for(i = 1; i = 3; i++) {
        printf("%.2f",b[i]);
    }

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

For those who were asking, the 2 functions ludcmp and lubksg are below. I got them from the numerical recipes textbook, but edited some lines to remove exclusive routines which I do not have. Specifically, they are the lines with malloc, printf, and free.

The original code came with all the loops starting with 1, which is why I also started my loop with 1. I have since changed all the loops to start from 0 instead, hopefully without introducing any new errors.

You can see the original code here:
https://github.com/saulwiggin/Numerical-Recipies-in-C/tree/master/Chapter2.Solution-of-Linear-Equations

Here is ludcmp:

```
void ludcmp(float a[3][3], int n, int *indx, float *d)
{
    int i, imax, j, k;
    float big, dum, sum, temp;
    float *vv;  // vv stores the implicit scaling of each row.

    vv = (float *) malloc(n * sizeof(float));

    *d=1.0;
    for (i=0;i<n;i++) {
        big=0.0;
        for (j=0;j<n;j++)
            if ((temp=fabs(a[i][j])) > big) big=temp;

        if (big == 0.0)
        {
            printf("Singular matrix in routine ludcmp");
            //free(vv);
        }

        // No nonzero largest element.
        vv[i] = 1.0 / big;       // Save the scaling.
    }

    // This is the loop over columns of Crout's method.
    for (j=0;j<n;j++) {
        for (i=0;i<j;i++) {
            sum=a[i][j];
            for (k=0;k<i;k++) sum -= a[i][k]*a[k][j];
            a[i][j]=sum;
        }

        // Initialize for the search for largest pivot element.
        big=0.0;
        for (i=j;i<=n;i++) {
            sum=a[i][j];
            for (k=0;k<j;k++)
                sum -= a[i][k]*a[k][j];
            a[i][j]=sum;
            if ( (dum=vv[i]*fabs(sum)) >= big) {
                big=dum;
                imax=i;
            }
        }
        if (j != imax) {
            for (k=0;k<n;k++) {
                dum=a[imax][k];
                a[imax][k]=a[j][k];
                a[j][k]=dum;
            }
            *d = -(*d);
            vv[imax]=vv[j];
        }
        indx[j]=imax;
        if (a[j][j] == 0.0) a[j][j]=TINY;
        if (j != n) {
            dum=1.0/(a[j][j]);
            for (i=j+1;i<n;i++) a[i][j] *= dum;
        }
    } // Go back for the next column in the reduction.

    free(vv);

}
```

And lubksb:

```
void lubksb(float a[3][3],int n,int *indx,float b[])

{
    int i,ii=0,ip,j;
    float sum;

    for (i=1;i<=n;i++) {
        ip=indx[i];
        sum=b[ip];
        b[ip]=b[i];
        if (ii)
            for (j=ii;j<=i-1;j++) sum -= a[i][j]*b[j];
        else if (sum) ii=i;
        b[i]=sum;
    }
    for (i=n;i>=1;i--) {
        sum=b[i];
        for (j=i+1;j<=n;j++) sum -= a[i][j]*b[j];
        b[i]=sum/a[i][i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you try to do: 
    for(i = 0; i <= sizeof(a);  i++)

Comment: In what way does it stop working? I mean does it freeze or crash or what? My suspicion is that it's freezing because of the loop mentioned by pvg and RGarcia

Comment: yes because is a bidemensional u need something like this: for (int i = 0; i < CITY; ++i) {
        for(int j = 0; j < WEEK; ++j) {
            printf("City %d, Day %d: ", i+1, j+1);
            scanf("%d", &temperature[i][j]);

Comment: In C (and many other languages) arrays start at 0

Comment: It's a great opportunity to learn how to use a debugger, which is something you should do sooner rather than later.

Comment: It is also an opportunity to get a book on C and look at the chapter on loops.

Comment: Where is the code of the two functions declared? ludcmp() and lubksb()?

Comment: You need a good C beginners book to read about pointers, loops, variables and memory in the C language

Comment: I have tried to start my loops from 0, but the problem still occurs. To address some comments, it's a windows prompt which appears, saying that the program.exe has stopped working. I'm using Dev-C++, which has a debugger. The program compiled without any errors, so the only problem occurs after double clicking the exe file

Comment: I have edited the question to add the 2 functions

Answer (score 1):

This is a Two Dimensional Array and you are looping as it was just one. You should do something like:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    for(int j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
        printf("%d %d: ", i+1, j+1);

    }
}
```

Is bad practice to define the size of the array explicit. Try to use a constant.

And as said in the comments by @Marged:

> In C arrays starts in 0

Answer (score 0):

`b` is never assigned to anything valid when it's declared:

```
float *b,d;
```

At best, it's NULL or pointing to an invalid memory address:

I don't know what the `lubksb` function does:

```
lubksb(a,n,indx,b);
```

But `b` is clearly an invalid parameter since you never assign to it before calling this function.

And with this statement:

```
for(i = 1; i = 3; i++) {
    printf("%.2f",b[i]);
}
```

As others have pointed out, array indices start at zero.  But there's no evidence that `b` has a length of three anyway.

Comment: You're missing another obvious issue, that `i=3` is an assignment, not comparison. (Hence why the program hangs)